# #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to access the PhpMyAdmin page, I had the error in the title above.

I tried all procedures found in the internet but unfortunately I didn't found the resolution.

Below the error that I have :

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

**Edit**:

Ichecked the Mysql service and I found that is not running, I try to start it but it won't.

Comment: Have you checked user host permissions for given user?

Comment: Yeah I had root user with all priveleges.

Comment: And what hosts is your user allowed to acess server?

Comment: local host because I do the job locally.

Answer (score 0):

I restart the machine and the things return to normal !! but when I edit the My.ini file in order to clean all added entries and restarted Mysql I had the same error and when I added skip-grant-tables option under [mysqld] in My.ini file I had once again access to Mysql !!!

I guess there is an issue in users or privileges !?